# Convertir un formato con texto a datetime

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo una columna(index) con valores en este formato, y necesito convertirlo a datestamp.

't_ene2015', 't_feb2015', 't_mar2015', 't_abr2015', 't_may2015', 't_jun2015', 't_jul2015', 't_ago2015', 't_sep2015', 't_oct2015', 't_nov2015', 't_dic2015',

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor realiza el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Que has intentado? Revisa [ask]

Answer (score 0):

puedes apoyarte en la función strptime, la cual recibe dos parámetros el primero es la cadena que se desea convertir a fecha y el segundo es el formato en el cual esta escrito donde %b se usa para indicar que es el mes y %Y el año como tus cadenas comienzan con t_ deberas agregarlo también. la cuestión a considerar es que esta funcion espera los meses en ingles jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dic

```
from datetime import datetime
 datetime_object = datetime.strptime('t_jun2015', 't_%b%Y')
```

espero sea de utilidad